# Do objects receive and return values?

Tags: php, object, return-value

My book has asked the question: "What is the difference between objects and functions?"

The answer key says that functions are sets of statements referenced by name that receive and return values.  It says that objects may have multiple functions, called methods; and multiple variables, called properties; all combined in a single unit.

Unfortunately, the book doesn't say whether or not objects receive and return values....  So, do they?  I'm trying to find an example.

Comment: Upvoted for good beginner question and answer. Although you have already accepted an answer for this question, I feel as though the answers haven't provided a full scope for understanding objects - if you have any questions, ask, and the community will try to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an object can be set up to be callable.

```
class Foo
{
  public function __invoke($arg)
  {
    echo "$arg\n";
  }
}

$f = new Foo();       // calls the __construct method if it exists
$f("Hello, World");   // calls the __invoke method.
```

But not all languages support such a concept, and it's not the norm.

I took a look at some of the other questions you have asked recently. Note that you *cannot* do this:

```
 Foo();
```

That does not make any sense since `Foo` is a class in this example.

Keep in mind that the term "object" refers to a specific instance (e.g., `new Foo()`) of a "class."

Comment: What are some language that don't support this?

Answer (score 1):

An object's methods are functions and, for the most part, work just like regular functions. The differences are that methods have different visibilities and have access to their object's properties without having to have them passed in.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by visibility (perhaps you mean scope)....  Also, the question isn't really about the methods' having return values, but more about the objects themselves.  Thank you for your answer, though.

Comment: @Fohsap: Visibility refers to the ability of a member to be accessed, while scope refers to the ability of a block of code to access a member, although most people will just say "scope" either way. *e.g.: the variable is not in **scope** (the variable is not **visible** from the current scope)*

Comment: Okay, so these appear to be a couple of more ways to differentiate between objects and functions.  Thank you, datasage and netcoder.